# HTML content in Custom Task Pane Outlook VSTO ADD in

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, customtaskpane

Is there any way to display a web page (or add HTML code) in the Custom Task Pane in Outlook 2016 COM (VSTO) AddIn similar to what we do in Iframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add a web browser control to your task pane and you can display any HTML content.